# Swift: How do i change existing UIButton larger hit area?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton

i've created an UIButton with larger hit area.
But now i want to change/adjust its hit area.
Anyway to change it without recreate UIButton object?

I see only pointInside function, but can't find any way to update larger hit area of specific UIButton?

```
var buttonMargin:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7,-2.5,-7,-2.5)
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let relativeFrame = self.bounds
    //var hitTestEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5, -5, -5, -5)
    let hitFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(relativeFrame, buttonMargin)
    return CGRectContainsPoint(hitFrame, point)
}
```